# How to receive data posted by "navigator.sendbeacon" on node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using new browser feature([navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)) to POST async data to node.js server.

But i am unable to receive it on node server. So could any one tell me how to receive data posted by sendBeacon on node server.

**node server code is:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// set cross origin header to allow cross-origin request.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/',function(req,res){
    console.log('i got the request',req.body)
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express is listening to http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**client side code**

```
navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:3000/','{"a":9}')
```

Comment: Please post your node server code.

Comment: @hassansin added server code too

Answer (score 46):

`navigator.sendBeacon` POST uses `Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8` to transmit string data. So just add `bodyParser.text()` to parse 'text/plain' data:

Server:

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text());
...
```

Client:

```
navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:3000/', JSON.stringify({a:9}));
```

#### Update

Apparently you can use [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) to add `Content-Type:application/json` header in your request:

Client:

```
var blob= new Blob([JSON.stringify({a:9})], {type : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}); // the blob
navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:3000/', blob )
```

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, and `text/plain` are the only permitted values for sendBeacon Content-Type now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274021/sendbeacon-api-not-working-temporarily-due-to-security-issue-any-workaround

Comment: For more recent versions of express, use `app.use(express.text())`

Answer (score 0):

we can send data by formData.

send data in client:

```js
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('resource', JSON.stringify({a:'test'}))
const success = navigator.sendBeacon('/api/url', formData)
```

receive data in server with express:

[Express js form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800511/express-js-form-data)

with koa2, I use `koa2-formidable` middleware only `/api/url` router.