Navigator.sendBeacon() sending ping and 403 Unknown Error
In my Java app,a jsp is calling another jsp as below,
\\ below function is inside abc.jsp
function sessionMark() {
  navigator.sendBeacon('logger.jsp');
  setTimeout(sessionMark, 2 * 60 * 1000 );
}

Also, the other jsp calls on abc.jsp page are all working and they are using ajax like below.
$.ajax({
  url: "VO.jsp",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {scripts:scripts,on: 'true',tb:'yes',},
  success: function(data) {
    //do something
  }
});

The logger.jsp is giving 403 Unknown error.
Edits:
I found that CorsFilter is applied on the tomcat web.xml as shown below.
 <filter>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
<param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>  

Additional details:
I have ldap verification on HTTPD server and the app resides in tomcat (Reverse proxy).
When the CorsFilter is removed, the API works and when it is on, the API fails.
Can someone explain why the jsp call not going through this ?

Please share (the relevant parts of) your code in logger.jsp. How exactly does it fail?

It was working before - before what? you made a change? undo the change

giving 403 Unknown error on browser console. @HeikoTheißen

@JaromandaX a few months back. I doubt it is something from browser which is not allowing the call in this fashion Navigator.sendBeacon()

I doubt it is something from browser ... I doubt it too ... I assumed you changed some code ... but the fact that it hasn't worked for "a few months" makes me wonder why you only ask about it now

@JaromandaX I was saying, it was working for a few months. Then somewhere it stopped. I noticed it recently. If it is browser specific, why am I able to access the other server(clone) without any error.

Could you please check this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274021/sendbeacon-api-not-working-temporarily-due-to-security-issue-any-workaround
They are also saying it was working in 2021.

If it is browser specific - nobody said it was browser specific - you changed something somewhere

You mention the CorsFilter, but does that actually have anything to do with this? The requests appear not to be cross-origin in the first place. Are you getting any CORS-related error messages anywhere? What is your server-side error logging saying about the reason for the 403 response?

@C3roe i have added more details to the question. Please see once.

Still not sure where CORS would come into play here. Both requests appear to go to relative URLs - unless you had some base URL configured somewhere, that would influence this? Maybe your server-side expects an Origin header, but doesn't get one (due to the requests not being cross-origin) - and then responds with a 403, based on that?

I cross checked with a working POST request. Content-Type and X-Requested-With headers are missing when sent through sendBeacon(). Any idea how to skip those ?

Figured out finally, The issue was caused due to the CorsFilter checking for a header Content-Type. This will not be set if you directly call the sendBeacon method.
I used the below code which will set the header by itself.
var params = new URLSearchParams({ some_value : 1 })
navigator.sendBeacon('logger.jsp',params);

