# Get an html attribute in node.js

Tags: node.js

Say I have a button like

```
<form action="/action1" method ="post">
<button type="submit" id="button1"> Click Me </button>
</form>
```

I want to get a value stored in the attributes (in this case "id") and do something like this

```
app.post('/action1', function (req, res) {
var buttonId = req.id // this is the part I dont understand
});
```

how would I fill in the line

```
var buttonId =
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The posted data does not include the `id` attribute. You can set the `name` and/or the `value` attribute and those will be part of the POST request. e.g.

```
<button type="submit" name="button1">Click Me</button>
```

To get to the posted data in express look here: [Express js form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800511/express-js-form-data)

Comment: if I print out my req.body.name it is undefined

Comment: The *content* of name (button1) is the key in the body. Please log the req.body to check.