# NodeJS TypeError: Post is not a Constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, typeerror

I got a formular and I want a response message after submitting it.
Is use Node v13.3.0,
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
"express-session": "^1.17.0",
"flash": "^1.1.0",
"handlebars": "^4.7.3",
"mongoose": "^5.9.2"

Post.js

```
const
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema; // get props

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    // define props --> required for a post

    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    biography: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    profilpicture: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    }


});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Controller.js

```
const Post = require('../models/postModel').Post;
module.exports = {
submitPosts: (req, res) => {
        // res.render('admin/posts/submit');
        // Check the attributs from create.handlebars for success or error message
        const newPost = new Post( {
            surname: req.body.surname,
            name: req.body.name,
            biography: req.body.biography,
            profilpicture: req.body.profilpicture
        });
        // Safe new posts
        newPost.save().then(post => {
            console.log(post);
            flash('success-message', 'Yay its fine')
            res.redirect('/admin');
        });
    },
}
```

The formular file I use for every input name="***attribut***" 
If I remove the Post (Controller.js) it throws another error:

*(node:2296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Post validation failed: surname: Path `surname` is required., name: Path `name` is required., biography: Path `biography` is required., profilpicture: Path `profilpicture` is required.*
and the site doesnt stop to load

Comment: Replace `require('../models/postModel').Post` with `require('../models/postModel')`, if that's the only thing it exports

Comment: already tried but then it throws a new error message: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Post validation failed: surname: Path `surname` is required., name: Path `name`.. and so on

Comment: Ok, my bad, didn't figure that out when first reading your question. However, that error is better than the other. So, do remove that `.Post`. Now that this is out of the way, do you see the correct data when you `console.log(req.body.surname)`, etc. before trying to create the `newPost`?

Comment: if i console.log(req.body.surname) before it says undefined and after it throws "Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)"

Answer (score 0):

If it logs `undefined` when you do this:

```
console.log(req.body.surname);
```

It means that you are not receiving the POST data as expected.

Make sure you're using [`express.urlencoded()`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.urlencoded) middleware:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // <--------

/* ... */
```

Comment: I use it in my app.js app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

Comment: Ok, how do you make the POST request, from the front-end? Could you add that to your question? The above should work if the form is sent as [x-www-form-urlencoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

Comment: For `form-data`, maybe [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44393295/1913729)?