# Access file upload formData in Express

Tags: node.js, express, upload, fetch

How can I access the files in the API?

**I read the other solutions and all of them require npm packages to solve this. I want to understand why I can't do it vanilla. Also, the answers are old and recommend using body-parser, which now comes bundled with Express.**

I would like the solution to be vanilla JS in order to understand the process better.

**client**

```js
async function uploadFile(file) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);

    let res = await fetchPostFile("/api/files", formData);
}
```

**fetch**

```js
export async function fetchPostFile(url, formData) {
    try {
        let result = await (
            await fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                withCredentials: true,
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
                body: formData,
            })
        ).json();

        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

**api**

```js
router.post("/api/files", async function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        console.log(req.file);          // undefined
        console.log(req.files);         // undefined
        console.log(req.body);          // {}

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } finally {
        req.connection.release();
    }
});
```

Why is the `req.body` empty? Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express js form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800511/express-js-form-data)

Comment: No, as body parser is built-in in Express, and the `req.body` is empty in my case. I asked this question after researching everything.

Comment: [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) is not built-in. However, since you're using `multipart/form-data` you'll need to use [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) instead. Both of these points are made in the answer I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the whole file management API.

I am using `busboy` which is what `multer` uses under the hood. I found it easier to use.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const config = require("../../config");

const busboy = require("busboy");
const fs = require("fs");

const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

let filesFolderPath = config.paths.files;

router.get("/api/records/:recordUid/files/:fieldUid", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let { recordUid, fieldUid } = req.params;

        let query = `
            select 
                rdf.*,
                r.uid recordUid,
                round(sizeBytes / 1024, 0) sizeKb,
                round(sizeBytes / 1024 / 1024, 0) sizeMb
            from recordDataFile rdf
                left join record r on r.id = rdf.recordId
                left join field f on f.id = rdf.fieldId
            where 
                r.uid = ?
                and f.uid = ?;
        `;

        let rows = await req.pool.query(query, [recordUid, fieldUid]);

        res.status(200).send(rows);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

router.get("/api/files/:hash", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let { hash } = req.params;

        let query = `
            select *
            from recordDataFile
            where hash = ?
        `;

        let rows = await req.pool.query(query, [hash]);
        let fileData = rows[0];

        res.download(fileData.path);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

router.post("/api/files", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let bb = busboy({
            headers: req.headers,
            defCharset: "utf8",
            limits: {
                fileSize: 20 * 1024 * 1024, // 20 mb
                files: 5,
            },
        });

        let fields = {};

        // Get any text values
        bb.on("field", (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) => {
            console.log(fieldname, val);
            fields[fieldname] = val;
        });

        // Read file stream
        bb.on("file", (fieldname, fileStream, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            // Prevents hieroglyphs from cyrillic
            let originalName = Buffer.from(filename.filename, "latin1").toString("utf8");

            let nameParts = originalName.split(".");
            let extension = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1]; // without the . from .jpeg

            // IMPORTANT!!! FILE NAME CAN'T HAVE SPACES, it won't save properly!!!
            let hash = SHA256(`${+new Date()}${originalName}`).toString();

            // Absolute path to file
            let filePath = `${filesFolderPath}${hash}`;

            // Open writeable stream to path
            let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

            // Pipe the file to the opened stream
            fileStream.pipe(writeStream);

            // Check for errors
            writeStream.on("error", (err) => {
                console.log("writeStream", err);
            });

            // Writing done, stream closed
            writeStream.on("close", async (err) => {
                // console.log("closing + SQL");

                if (err) {
                    console.log("closing error");
                    return;
                }

                let query = `
                    insert into recordDataFile
                        (
                            recordId,
                            fieldId,
                            name,
                            extension,
                            hash,
                            path,
                            sizeBytes,
                            userId,
                            created
                        )
                    values
                        (
                            (select id from record where uid = ?),
                            (select id from field where uid = ?),
                            ?,
                            ?,
                            ?,
                            ?,
                            ?,
                            ?,
                            now()
                        );
                `;

                let sizeBytes = fs.statSync(filePath).size;

                await req.pool.query(query, [fields.recordUid, fields.fieldUid, originalName, extension, hash, filePath, sizeBytes, req.userId]);

                // record updated. send notification?
                await req.pool.query(`update record set updated = now(), updatedByUserId = ? where uid = ?`, [req.userId, fields.recordUid]);
            });
        });

        bb.on("finish", () => {
            res.status(200).send({ success: true });
        });

        req.pipe(bb); // Hooks the streams together. Without it, you're not feeding busboy any data to parse.
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("file upload catch", err);
        next(err);
    }
});

router.delete("/api/files/:hash", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let { hash } = req.params;

        // get the file
        let query = `
            select * from recordDataFile where hash = ?
        `;

        let rows = await req.pool.query(query, [hash]);

        let file = rows[0];
        let filePath = file.path;

        // remove file
        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);

        // delete the file metadata
        await req.pool.query(` delete from recordDataFile where hash = ?`, [hash]);

        res.status(200).send(rows);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 8):

First you need to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) package to handle `multipart/form-data` in express. You must use it as a middleware to set the field name for the file. The name passed as an argument to the `single()` function must match to the appended name on client side.

```
const multer = require('multer')

router.post("/api/files", multer().single('file'), async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
      console.log(req.file)
  } catch (err) {
      next(err)
  } finally {
      req.connection.release()
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do I need a package for this? I specifically asked for a vanilla way to do this.

Comment: I get that, but why is Multer required?

Comment: You tried to send form-data, but you didn't tell the express that it should expect form-data. Multer gives ability to handle the form-data that the client sends.

Comment: So you're saying that you MUST use a library, i.e. Express doesn't support it as is.

Comment: Why do you want do it with vanilla js, if there are tools that makes your work easier?

Comment: Just to understand the process. Is it bad to learn? I don't want to just blindly add dependencies.

Comment: It works the vanilla way with Python flask for example, I assume it should be possible with express too.

Comment: Just to add here, Multer is a recommended way to access the file by Express.
Refer: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Comment: Multer isn’t really an external package in the way I think you mean it. It’s basically standard.